# Use Django Permission in Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, datatable, permissions

I used Django Permission in Django Template before like `{% if perms.assets.change_log %}` and it works.

I want to this to render a server-side datatable in JavaScript but it failed, like

```
<script>
console.log(perm.assets.change_log)
</script>
```

There is nothing output on the console.

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
console.log({{ perm.assets.change_log|safe }})
</script>
```

try this

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It perfectly solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This solution work for me finely.
first in django view add:

```
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
    context = {
        'dataModel': 'your_data',
        'perms': PermWrapper(self.request.user)
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

and then in index.html and javascript code :

```
      var canEdit = {% if perms.YourApplication.change_model %}true{% else %}false{% endif %};
      if (canEdit) {
           //do something.....
          }
          else{
              return null;
          }
```